# Python: What is wrong with this identation?

Tags: python, indentation

```
counter = 0

with open("vejman_admdata.gml") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 300:
            break
```

I get the following message:

```
E:\01_projekter\Utils\vejman>test.py >log.txt
  File "E:\01_projekter\Utils\vejman\test.py", line 7
    counter += 1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: Probably your are mixing tabs & spaces

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces, I went to edit your code and if you move the cursor on each line through the indents you can see the cursor jump

Comment: It was the tabs and spaces... :(

Comment: Thanks! - this was a stupid mistake. Have to get used to the identation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit your question:

[image]

You're mixing tabs and spaces.